# Having error using cached files on IOS in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, caching

I am working on a flutter application. I have implemented caching using *`flutter_cache_manager`*, and everything works just fine, except the files are saved with `.bin` extension.

When i use these files, they work perfectly on `Android`, but doesn't work on IOS. My files are video format, and on IOS, they're not getting `initialized`.

```
localVid(var setState1) async {
    try {
      if(mounted) {
        String videoPath = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8371AD75-B1E6-467A-98C4-550AD2977F54/Library/Caches/video_cache/b9b7b820-d635-11ee-be0e-65eb586d22f7.bin";
 
        if(videoPath.trim().isNotEmpty) {
          _lVideoPath = videoPath;
          var controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(videoPath));
          _videoController = controller;
          if(mounted) {
            controller.initialize().then((_) {
              controller.addListener(_onControllerUpdate);
              if(mounted) {
                setState1(() {
                  isVidInit = true;
                });
              }
            });
          }
        } else {
          print("Url Doesn't exist Or there is an error that has occurred!");
          if(mounted) {
            setState1(() {
              errorInitVid = true;
            });
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error Occurred Initializing Video: ${e}");
      if(mounted) {
        setState1(() {
          errorInitVid = true;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

What could be the issues, is there something I am missing, or is there something wrong here?

Thanks